# X Windows events on Linux

Tags: linux, x11

I'm trying to teach myself out of curiosity how to grab events between two or more X windows on Linux. So far I'm a terrible hack at it and can only get the FocusIn and FocusOut events.

Anyone have any advice or quick tutorials on how to do this the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you look at the source code to xev and xwininfo  and see how they derive their information.

xev is like spy++ for windows and captures all sorts of events in real time:
`xev -id $(xwininfo | awk '/Window id/ { print $4 }')`

xwininfo is more of a static tool to learn more about the properties of the window.